# Dualshock 4 key stopped working and the controlller dont reset

Tags: ps4, controllers

Well... basically I matched my  dualshock 4 on my cellphone to play a Nintendo emulator... done a couple of times already actually...

Problem is, after the last time I done it, the controller stopped to behave normally with my ps4, the L2 key stop working at random times and the controller refuse to reset (tried about 5 to 6 times already)...

Done some research to fix the problem, but to no avail till now...

Can anyone help me?